# Finding the biggest amongst the smallest

Tags: sql

I need help with a problem from my SQL test.

Let's say I have two tables, Album (album_id) and DailySells (album_id, date, albums_sold) and joined them

```
+----------+------+-------------+
| album_id | date | albums_sold |
+----------+------+-------------+
|     1111 |   11 |           2 |
|     1111 |   22 |           3 |
|     1111 |   33 |           4 |
|     2222 |   11 |           4 |
|     2222 |   22 |           7 |
|     2222 |   33 |           1 |
|     3333 |   11 |           0 |
|     3333 |   22 |           9 |
|     3333 |   33 |           2 |
+----------+------+-------------+
```

The question is: show the best selling album among the worst selling albums by day.

So I need to get the worst selling albums on each day and then extract the best selling one of them. I can see that the answer should show 1111 (date 22, albums_sold 3).

Can you help me with writing a query that would solve this problem?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm sorry, I was breaking my head for more than 3 hours on this one, but didn't show the code. Here's what I've been trying with:

```
select id
from album join daily using(id)
where (date, albsold) in (select date, min(albsold)
    from daily
    group by date
    having min(albsold) = (select max(worstdaily)
                           from (select date, min(albsold) as worstdaily
                                 from daily
                                 group by date) as inner))
```

Comment: at least make an attempt at writing the query, and then tell us where you are having issues.

Comment: Here is a page to get you started, you should also tag with what database you are using (MySql, Sql Server etc.) https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/selecting-only-one-row-per-group

Comment: Start by getting the list of worst selling albums

Comment: I didn't get your logic. By singling out 1111, you seem to be saying you want the worst selling album by day.. e.g. on day 22 , 1111 was the worst seller. Where does the "best selling" aspect come into this? 1111 hasnt been an all time best seller (across all days, total sale = 9, vs 11 for the other 2) and you could only reasonably say it was a best seller on day 33 with 4 sales vs 2 or 1 for the other albums. All albums have been best sellers on one of the days (1111 best on 33, 2222 best on 11, 3333 best on 22)

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I've shown my code in the post. I'm not sure, we're writing code on paper so I guess it's SQL Server.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thank you, that's what I've started with, but kinda got lost when trying to extract the best selling one.

Comment: @CaiusJard Maybe I didn't put it clearly. The task is to find worst selling albums (3333 worst on day 11 with 0 sells, 1111 on day 22 with 3 sells and 2222 on day 33 with 1 sell) and then extract the best one amongst those (1111 on day 22 with 3 sells).

Comment: I'm now on stackowerflow so forgive me for any annoying stuff I may be doing. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the second best selling album the best selling album amongst the worst selling albums?

Comment: You should always tag SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. As this seems to be a general SQL test, I suppose you want an answer with standard SQL, but you should at least mention this in your request.

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto It's the best albums_sold in a table that shows worst selling album of every day.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks and sorry for not giving the complete info. I'm new here and don't really know much about depths of my problem in SQL. As far as I know this is it - the problem and standard SQL querries, pen on paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this. In any way, we must keep in mind that there may be ties (multiple worst sellers on a day or multiple best sellers among the worst) and decide how to go about this. I'm considering all rows that tie, so the result may span multiple rows.

Here are some standard SQL queries. Your DBMS may or may not support them.

**Query 1**

```
select album_id
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where other.date = mytable.date
  and other.albums_sold < mytable.albums_sold
)
order by albums_sold desc
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

**Query 2**

```
select album_id
from
(
  select album_id, albums_sold, rank() over (partition by date order by albums_sold) as rn
  from mytable other
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by albums_sold desc
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

**Query 3**

```
select album_id
from
(
  select album_id, albums_sold
  from mytable other
  order by rank() over (partition by date order by albums_sold)
  fetch first 1 row with ties
) worst
order by albums_sold desc
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

You see you can combine the methods: subquery, rank, fetch first.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your solutions are getting me the right result.

Unfortunately fetch isn't something we've covered in class, I think we are expected to solve this using MIN and MAX functions.

I think I might have managed to work it out, you can see it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dt4b7uoH19deAJnwtzTw3F/0).

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Your query is correct. You don't have to join with `album` though, because you get the album `id` from `dnpr` already. You'd only have to join with `album`, if it contained a title or other data you wanted to show.

Comment: You're right, the task said to show the album title. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In subquery we take only record with MIN(albums_sold) value by dates, then sort by albums_sold DESC and with TOP(1) we take the MAX  :

```
SELECT TOP(1) mt.* 
FROM alb mt INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, MIN(albums_sold) MinSold
    FROM alb
    GROUP BY date
) t ON mt.date = t.date AND mt.albums_sold = t.MinSold
ORDER BY albums_sold DESC
```

Comment: Because the question is tagged with the sql tag only you should keep the answer ISO/IEC (ANSI) standard SQL only.. This answer seams to be SQL Server (MSSQL) SQL dialect